# Load custom view in phonegap/iphone

Tags: iphone, cordova

I have made a plugin for the iphone which is working fine. I can call all the native methods. I also made a custom view (.xib file) which i want to load. But i can't figure out how to do this with phonegap in the way.

Normally i would do something like:

```
[self addSubView:myView2];
```

But this doesn't work.

Anyone any idea how to load and display a custom made .xib file when using phonegap??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you used [Child browser plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/ChildBrowser) so far, this plugin also contain ChildBrowserViewController.xib . So to call another xib in your Phonegap you need to modify your`- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType`
method in appDelgate.m file.

Some how in your HTML and javascript code, you need to provide special link (using href or window.location method) that you need to handle in `shouldStartLoadWithRequest`method, import your `#import MyCustomViewController.h` in your appDelegate.m file.

Please have look at the following snippet-

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    //return [ super webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType ];
    NSURL *url = [request URL];
    if([request.URL.absoluteString isEqualToString:@"about:blank"])
        return [ super webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request
                navigationType:navigationType ];
    if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"gap"]) {
        return [ super webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request
                navigationType:navigationType ];
    } 
        else {
        NSString *urlFormat = [[[url path] componentsSeparatedByString:@"."] lastObject];
        if ([urlFormat compare:@"xib"] == NSOrderedSame) {
            [theWebView sizeToFit];
            MyCustomViewController* customVC = [ [ MyCustomViewController alloc ] initWithScale:FALSE ];
            customVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
            customVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
            [super.viewController presentModalViewController:customVC animated:YES ];           
            [customVC release];
            //return YES;
            return NO;  
        } 
        else
            return [ super webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request
                    navigationType:navigationType ];    
    } 
}
```

thanks,
mayur