# Include Phonegap / Cordova plugin in the WebView

Tags: javascript, cordova, webview, phonegap-plugins

I wonder if it's possible to include a Cordova plugin inside a webview. All Cordova plugins I've seen trigger an external ressource (Camera) and/or return a string result.
I'd like to write a plugin that I can put in my WebView inside a DOM element.

For example a drawing plugin, a map plugin, or any native control that I'd include inside the WebView.

Comment: From what I have found, you can do that with iOS but not with android. Though, I am more familiar with iOS than Android so I may not have found the correct way to do it in Android. In iOS you can use native code to add subviews to the main webview.

Comment: I'd like to know how do you get that to work. Also I found : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8210400/load-custom-view-in-phonegap-iphone and http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.handhelds.phonegap/16544

Comment: I'll try to find my test code from when I did it in iOS and post it here. I added a mapview to the webview and it seemed to work.